# Swift 3. NSFetchRequest propertiesToFetch

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, nsfetchrequest

In Swift 3 when we use `NSFetchRequest`, we have to specify `NSFetchRequestResult`. But how to get an array of properties values? If I use something like this

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<MyClass>(entityName: "MyClass")
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["myAttributeName"]
```

an exception fires when I try to execute fetch request.
`error: -executeRequest: encountered exception = The database appears corrupt.`
If I remove a line with `propertiesToFetch` I don't get any errors, but I get an array of objects, not properties.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The problem was I forgot to set `fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot to set `resultType` for NSFetchRequest.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<MyClass>(entityName: "MyClass")
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["myAttributeName"]
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you are better off in most cases using the array of objects rather than properties. Core Data will manage the optimal load balancing for round trips to the store for you. What you presumably worry about most (memory, performance, data access times) is really not warranted.

Also, this should result in cleaner, safer and more concise code.

Comment: What about fetching unique properties only? Is it still better to use objects and then run a map, and set on them? Or is it better to fetch properties and set the fetch request to return distinct results?

Comment: I would use the latter method. Extracting unique values should be more efficient when done on the database level.